Delphi 2009 can not compare '' with 333 while Delphi 6 could: "Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Double)" in Delphi 2009
I am trying to migrate a Delphi 6 application with TdxDBGrid to Delphi 2009, and for the time being I would like to keep TdxDBGrid, because it has features that TcxGrid does not (we're moving to TcxGrid generally). I am stuck on this error that appears when the user enters a new line and a new numeric value in the TdxDBGrid:

Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Double)

I traced that the error is very generic - it all boils down how '' is converted to Double (e.g. to 333). Delphi 2009 has this routine (from Delphi RTL Variants.pas):
function VarToDoubleAsString(const V: TVarData): Double;
var
  S: WideString;
  LValue: Extended;
  LResult: HResult;
begin
  _VarToWStr(S, V);
  LResult := VarR8FromStr(S, VAR_LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, Result);
  case LResult of
    VAR_OK:; // in this case the OS function has put the value into result
    VAR_TYPEMISMATCH:
      if TryStrToFloat(S, LValue) then
        Result := LValue
      else
        VarResultCheck(VAR_TYPEMISMATCH, V.VType, varDouble);
  else
    VarResultCheck(LResult, V.VType, varDouble);
  end;
end;

but Delphi 6 has this routine:
function VarToRealAsString(const V: TVarData): Extended;
var
  S: String;
  LValue: Double;
  LResult: HResult;
begin
  _VarToLStr(S, V);
  LResult := VarR8FromStr(S, $400, 0, LValue);
  if LResult = VAR_OK then
    Result := LValue
  else if not TryStrToFloat(S, Result) then                             
    VarResultCheck(LResult, varString, varDouble);  
end;

The problems starts with LResult := VarR8FromStr(S, VAR_LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, Result); where a type mismatch is returned, and the flow branches down to TryStrToFloat(S, LValue) which fails somehow. It is hard to imagine why TryStrToFloat('', very-small-number) can fail, but this code:
function TryStrToFloat(const S: string; out Value: Extended): Boolean;
begin
  Result := TextToFloat(PChar(S), Value, fvExtended);
end;

suggests that Try... may expect a Unicode string, but all the processing up to this point has been done with WideString and that is why the conversion is being done by:
procedure _UStrFromWStr(var Dest: UnicodeString; const Source: WideString);
asm
        { ->    EAX pointer to dest                 }
        {       EDX pointer to WideString data      }
        
        XOR     ECX,ECX
        TEST    EDX,EDX
        JZ      @@1            // nil source => zero length
        MOV     ECX,[EDX-4]
        SHR     ECX,1          // length in WideString is byte count
@@1:    JMP     _UStrFromPWCharLen
end;

And there is some mess. I don't understand this part, but either:

WideString '' can not be converted to UnicodeString, or


very_small_number is not appropriate as the default value.

So - if I can correct something in those Variant handling procedures and add this corrected Variants.pas file to my project, then I could live with the old TdxDBGrid for some time.
So - does anyone have experience with a similar migration problem with exactly this type of Variant handling, Variant conversion code, and they know and can suggest a more or less safe correction to Variant handling/conversion procedures?

Why are you migrating to Delphi 2009 instead of a modern version? Delphi 2009 is 15 years old, and It's also the version that introduced UnicodeString, so it makes sense that there may have been some problems back then as they were still ironing out issues with it and fixed in later versions.

In any case, I can verify that this issue still exists in the latest Delphi 12.2. Assigning a Variant holding a blank string to a Double uses the same VarToDoubleAsString() that you quoted (except that sometime after 10.3, it was changed to attempt TryStrToFloat() before VarR8FromStr()). Delphi 7 made the switch from VarToRealAsString() to VarToDoubleAsString(), which means for over 20 years you can't convert a blank string Variant to a Double. So, the code that is trying to do that conversion needs to be updated to check the Variant is not holding a blank string beforehand

The fact that Delphi 6 returned value of 333 for an empty string should be considered a bug. It should have not returned any value since it is impossible to convert empty string into numerical value. It is like I give you an empty pice of paper and ask you to read me the number is from that piece of paper. Would you be able to give me an answer?

@SilverWarior No, entering of 333 in the cell of the new record of the DevExpress grid has lead to the DevExpress code that compared the existing value of the cell (it is '' for the empty cell of new record, of course) to the new value (333) and this comparison lead to the Variants code of converting '' to the double. I will check tomorrow the more bare code and - most likely - I will correct DevExpress comparison function so, that it replaces '' with 0 in the case, when numerical value is entered.

Actually DevExpress TdxDBGrid was not meant for Delphi 2009 (first Unicode version), but we ported it and experienced this error. DevExpress offers TcxGrid for the Unicode Delphi version, which is completely rewritten and some non-intersecting features.

You can change how Delphi converts a variant string to a double. So you could tell Delphi to convert an empty string to a double with the value 0.0. There is a risk that you hide other bugs with this instead of fixing them. So be careful.
uses VarUtils;

{$IF compilerversion >= 24}
function MyVarR8FromStr(const strIn: PWideChar; LCID: Integer; dwFlags: Integer;
  out dblOut: Double): HRESULT; stdcall;
const
  CResult: array [False..True] of HRESULT = (VAR_TYPEMISMATCH, VAR_OK);
begin
  if StrLen(strIn) = 0 then
  begin
    Result := VAR_OK;
    dblOut := 0.0;
  end
  else
    Result := CResult[TryStrToFloat(strIn, dblOut)];
end;
{$ELSE}
function MyVarR8FromStr(const strIn: WideString; LCID: Integer; dwFlags: Longint;
    out dblOut: Double): HRESULT; stdcall;
const
  CResult: array [False..True] of HRESULT = (VAR_TYPEMISMATCH, VAR_OK);
begin
  if strIn = '' then
  begin
    Result := VAR_OK;
    dblOut := 0.0;
  end
  else
    Result := CResult[TryStrToFloat(strIn, dblOut)];
end;
{$IFEND}

initialization
  VarUtils.VarR8FromStr := MyVarR8FromStr;
end.

